# Django model reference and manipulation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have the following models in Django that have a structure as follows:

```
class Office_Accounts(models.Model):
    accountid                       =   models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    validtill                       =   models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    limit                           =   models.CharField(max_length=2)

class Device(models.Model):
    device_type         = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    serial_number       = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    in_use_by           = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    brand               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    model               = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="-", null=False)
    type_number         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True, default = None)
    mac_address         = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True, default = None)
    invoice             = models.FileField(upload_to='Device_Invoice', null=True, blank = True)
    msofficeaccount     = models.ForeignKey(Office_Accounts, to_field="accountid")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Devices"

    def full_name(self):
        return self.device_type + self.serial_number + self.brand
```

I will display both of the models in admin.py. 
Now, I want to display the count of each accountid present in the field "msofficeaccount" (present in Device Models) in my admin page of Office_Accounts model. For an example if xyz@abc.com appears in 10 rows of msofficeaccount field then, the count should be displayed as 10 in Office_Accounts admin page. Can anyone please guide me how should I approach this problem to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method to your admin class that returns the count of related devices for each office_account, but that would be very inefficient. Instead you can override `get_queryset` to annotate the count from a database aggregation function:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class Office_AccountsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'device_count')
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.annotate(device_count=Count('device'))
```

(On a minor note, Python style is always to use CamelCase for class names, and Django style is to use singular model names, so your model should really be called OfficeAccount.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Let me check it out and reply back to you asap.

Comment: I am using python 2, in that case I will need to pass an argument with super() right? In this case what would be the argument?

Comment: The argument is always (current class, self) so `(Office_AccountsAdmin, self)`. But really you should upgrade, recent versions of Django aren't even compatible with Python 2.

Comment: But the code that you provided to me will return the count from the present class right? whereas, I wanted the count from a different class that uses a particular field of Office_Accounts as a foreign key. In this case how will I be able to do it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code will add to each row of Office_Accounts a field containing the number of Devices that are related to it. Is that not what you want?